# RegEx for replacing specific words not between quotation marks

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to replace `Hello` in the string `s`with another word if the word is NOT between quotations marks such as " " or ' '. Let us pretend the replacement word is Matt so,

This is the input:

```
s = 'Hello How Are you, "hey Hello", \'ney Hello\'. Hello I\'m great'
```

Desired output:

```
s = 'Matt How are you, "hey Hello", \'ney Hello\'. Matt I\'m great '
```

I have searched around and come across this code and with little modification I manage to replace the word successfully but it only works with ' ' and not " " included

```
import re

def replace_method(match):

    if match.group(1) is None:
        return match.group()

    return match.group().replace("Hello", "Matt")

s = 'Hello How Are you, "hey Hello", \'ney Hello\'. Hello I\'m great'

output = re.sub(r"'[^']*'|([^']*)", replace_method, s)
print(output)
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answers, but I missed to explain something important (which I first noticed, in my defense, after executing the successful code), "obviously" I don't want this sentence:

`s = "Hellona, how are you"`

to become

`s = "Markna, how are you"`

So, the regex should include that the word I'm trying to replace is not surronded by *NUMBERS* or *LETTERS*.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement callback looks fine.

The regex though, needs to be this

`r"('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")|\b[Hh]ello\b"`

Readable  version

```
   (                             # (1 start)
        ' [^']* '
     |  
        " [^"]* "
   )                             # (1 end)
|  
   \b [Hh]ello \b
```

---

Note that I think the group 1 check in the callback
has to be true if group 1 matched.

Not a Python programmer, but should it be something like

```
if match.group(1) :
    return match.group()
return "Matt"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but why exactly is [Hh]ello added at the end of the regex?

Comment: Well, I believe that is what you're trying to match. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Is it also possible to check if the word is not surrounded by letters or numbers, for example, this sentence: "Hellona hey", obviously I don't want Hellona to become Markna. –

Comment: Oh, that wasn't in the original question. Try starting a new question.

Comment: First of I accidentely downvoted your post. And I cannot upvote it before you edit it. So is it really necessary - I start a new question. I can do that, but at least edit it a bit. So I can upvote (or at least remove my downvote). You are missing a : in the if statement :)

Comment: Added a `:` at end of python conditional, and word boundary's `\b` in regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re


def replace_word(input, search, replace):
    def replace_method(match):
        if match.group(2) is None:
            return match.group()
        return match.group(2).replace(search, replace)
    expr = re.compile("('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")|({})".format(search))
    return re.sub(expr, replace_method, s)

s = 'Hello How Are you, "hey Hello", \'ney Hello\'. Hello I\'m great'

output = replace_word(s, "Hello", "Matt")
print(output)
```

You can match everything between single or double quotes in group 1(`('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")`), then your word in group 2 (`{}`, formatted with the `search` term), then replace group 2 with whatever you want.

Comment: Hello, this is just an addition to the question. Is it also possible to check if the word is not surrounded by letters or numbers, for example, this sentence: "Hellona hey", obviously I don't want Hellona to become Markna.

Comment: Well with that function you can search for a regexp, it'll format it into the compiled expression. Could be "[\W]*hello[\W]*" for hello surrounded by either nothing, or anything but letters, digits or underscores for example

Answer (score -1):

Here, we might be able to solve this problem with:

```
([^'"]?)(Hello)([^'"])
```

which we can replace it with:

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WvYqc4/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

This snippet shows that we might likely have a valid expression:

```js
const regex = /([^'"]?)(Hello)([^'"])/gm;
const str = `Hello How Are you, "hey Hello", 'ney Hello'. Hello I'm great. "Hello' I'm great`;
const subst = `$1Matt$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([^'\"]?)(Hello)([^'\"])"

test_str = "Hello How Are you, \"hey Hello\", 'ney Hello'. Hello I'm great. \"Hello' I'm great"

subst = "\1Matt\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

---

For excluding `Hellona`, we can add a word boundary:

```
([^'"]?)(\bHello\b)([^'"])
```

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /([^'"]?)(\bHello\b)([^'"])/gm;
const str = `Hello How Are you, "hey Hello", 'ney Hello'. Hello I'm great. "Hello' I'm great. Hellona how are you? `;
const subst = `$1Matt$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Very nice is it possible to elaborate on the last part of the question concerning s = "Hellona, how are you", becoming s = "Markna, how are you". If Hello is Hellone, it will still get replaced with Mark in your code.